# Detect DEBUG, RELEASE and my own mode C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, configuration

I have DEBUG, RELEASE and MYMODE configuration modes. How can I detect them?

```
#if DEBUG
#endif
```

detect only DEBUG and anything else, but not difference between RELEASE and MYMODE.
How can I do it?

**MORE INFO:**

I was thinking about something like this:

```
#if DEBUG
#elif RELEASE
#elif MYMODE
```

but if I have RELEASE or MYMODE, all parts of code are gray, only for DEBUG mode the DEBUG part is colorful. I also tried

```
#define MYMODE
```

but for this, MYMODE is true all the time doesn't metter what mode is set.

Comment: Why should `#DEBUG` "detect" a `#RELEASE` or even an arbitrary, completely unrelated symbol?

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't need `RELEASE` because `!DEBUG` should mean the same thing. Secondly, how are you defining your conditional compilation symbols?

Comment: I did not define anything. I tried #define MYMODE but it is true all the time doesn't metter what mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyMode is a *configuration*. But, in and of itself, that doesn't define *any* conditional compilation symbols.

You change these through the projects compilation settings<sup>1</sup> or by passing the [`-define`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/define-compiler-option) option to csc. If you look through the Debug configuration's compilation settings, you'll find that the `DEBUG` conditional compilation symbol was already defined<sup>2</sup>, but there's no `RELEASE` symbol defined in the Release configuration.

There is no requirement (as you'll find above) that there be any relation between configurations and the symbols that they define.

[`#if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) (and family) is defined to work with conditional compilation.

---

<sup>1</sup>Project -> Properties -> Build -> General.

<sup>2</sup>In some versions of Visual Studio, there's a dedicated checkbox for it rather than it being listed in the Conditional Compilation symbols, but the effect is the same. If you unload the project and examine the XML, you'll find that all constants are stored in the `<DefineConstants>` element.

Answer (score 3):

First you can use boolean operators in `#if`:

```
#if DEBUG || MYMODE
…
#endif
```

Second you can use `#else` and `#elif` to break up things...

```
#if DEBUG
// Debug only
#elif MYMODE || RELEASE
// In either release or MYMODE
#else
// Otherwise
#endif
```

The combination of these two covers most use cases.

Comment: I tried #if DEBUG #elif RELEASE #elif MYMODE, but all parts of code were gray when I had Release or Mymode, only for Debug was it's part colorful. So I'm confused if it works only for debug or if its some vs bug.

Comment: @BananaCake Check the solution configuration maps to the right project configuration *and* the project's build settings are right. Also sometimes VS doesn't pickup config changes without a restart. Also this won't work for files opened that are not part of a project (eg. doing clever things with linked files).

Comment: Actually @Richard is right!!! you need to restart VS everytime you need to run DEBUG or RELEASE Mode code. at least in Xamarin.Forms works like that. in VS2019

Answer (score 0):

The same:

```
#if MYMODE
#endif

#if RELEASE
#endif
```

Or [more complex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if):

```
#if (DEBUG && MYMODE)
#endif

#if (!RELEASE && MYMODE)
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution also thanks by you guys. I used this code:

```
#if DEBUG
#elif MYMODE
#else
```

but first I needed to put the name `MYMODE` to the Properties > Build > Conditional Compilation Symbols. I didn't do it before so there was the problem.